Events Rendering Customization
I want to change the flow of how FullCalendar ReactJS component render my multi-days events (Three or more days), I am using the calendar with initial view as dayGridMonth, and I want to render my events only at the start date of the event, and end date of the event, I don't want to events to be rendered in the days between.
This is my declaration for the component, I will add below the function dateHasEvent and renderEventContent.
<FullCalendar
            ref={calendarRef}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            themeSystem="bootstrap"
            dayMaxEvents={0}
            direction={isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}
            stickyHeaderDates={false}
            editable={false}
            selectable={false}
            selectMirror
            eventTimeFormat={eventTimeFormat}
            events={events}
            initialDate={new Date()}
            style={{ fontSize: '5px' }}
            headerToolbar={{
              start: 'title',
              center: '',
              end: `today prev,next`
            }}
            buttonText={{
              today: t('common:today'),
              month: t('common:month'),
              week: t('common:week'),
              day: t('common:day'),
              list: t('common:list')
            }}
            moreLinkDidMount={args => dateHasEvent(args)}
            eventContent={renderEventContent}
          />

const dateHasEvent = info => {
  const dayCell = info?.el?.closest('.fc-daygrid-day');

  if (dayCell) {
    const datCellNumber = dayCell?.querySelector('.fc-daygrid-day-number');

    if (datCellNumber) {
      datCellNumber?.classList?.add('has-event');
    }

    const dayEvents = dayCell
      ?.querySelector('.fc-daygrid-day-events')
      ?.querySelector('.fc-daygrid-day-bottom');

    if (dayEvents) {
      const dayEventsLink = dayEvents?.querySelector('a');

      if (dayEventsLink) {
        dayCell?.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
          let popOver = document?.querySelector('.fc-popover');

          if (popOver) {
            popOver?.querySelector('.fc-popover-close').click();
          }

          dayEventsLink?.click();
        });
      }

      dayEvents?.classList?.add('day-cell-events-removal');
    }
  }
};

const renderEventContent = eventInfo => {
  if (!eventInfo.isEnd && !eventInfo.isStart) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {eventInfo.isStart && eventInfo.isStart != eventInfo.isEnd && (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            padding: '5px 0px 5px 0px',
            borderRadius: '20px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }}
        >
          {eventInfo.event.title}
        </div>
      )}
      {eventInfo.isEnd && (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            padding: '5px 5px 5px 5px',
            borderRadius: '20px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }}
        >
          {eventInfo.event.title}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

Function renderEventContent will check if the event is at start date or end date or not, based on that it will render the event with a specific color, or return null.
Function dateHasEvent will check if the a day has an event or not, as I am doing a bit of customization on the day cell itself if there is at least one event, and here is my problem.
My problem is even if the renderEventContent return null, it will still show that the day of that event has an event, so it will be like I have a day with event, but looking into the details of that day, no are no events.

IMO this is a bizarre requirement. Why do you want to make it look like there isn't an event on a given day, when there actually is? Surely that's confusing for users? What's the use case?? Anyway I think you'll find it extremely difficult to muck around with fullCalendar's rendering to such an extent that it will hide these reliably and neatly. A better solution might be to feed the calendar 2 single events representing the start and end of the real multi-day event as held in your data store.

Thank you @ADyson for you suggestion, it worked perfectly, and it achieved what I wanted to do. The use case of this requirement is as a user may have events with durations of more than two weeks for example, this will lead to have almost half of the months showing that there is an event, and at the same of that time, there might be a shorter events that will start and finish before thee long one finish. so for easier events flagging to the user, we are going with approach
